# is there a way to change cloudapp.net DNS name in windows Azure

Tags: azure

I setup my VM in windows Azure, and I didn't fully understand how it would all work together at the time, so I gave my cloud service a weird DNS name, and now I want to change it.  Is there a way to change my .cloudapp.net DNS name?  I really don't wanna have to delete my whole cloud service and all my VMs just to change the cloud service DNS.  I know I can use a custom domain with CNAME or A Records, but that only affects production and forwarding etc...  I want my cloudapp.net DNS to have a different name.  Is that possible?  Or do I have to delete everything and start over from the beginning?

Comment: Nope, it's that forever unless you remove it and recreate it.

Comment: okay, thanks.  you wanna repost this as an answer so I can mark it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's currently impossible to change the name without deleting and recreating the service. I think this is because they have to reserve expensive (DNS) resources dynamically and they try to minimize the strain on these systems, but this is pure speculation.

Answer (score 1):

It's an old post but I can help someone else.

When you created the VM (Cloud Service), it was automatically created a separated Storage. So you can create another Cloud Service - with the new name you want - using this Storage and delete the old one. I've already made it successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can target an IP with a name from any domain name registration service.

For example, if on Azure you created a site called weirdclowndonkey.cloudapp.net and you would rather it be trustbank.com, you can do the following:

1) register a name anywhere (here's a search all ready for you: https://www.google.com/search?q=domain+name+registration )

2) find the ip address of your server on azure

3) enter that ip address as the target on the website of the domain name registration site.