# SQL Azure aliasing DNS name

Tags: sql, azure, dns, azure-sql-database

We are setting up some Azure SQL databases that will be accessed by our clients for reporting purposes. When the database is setup in Azure, the SQL server name is in the form server.database.windows.net. Is there some way I can alias the dns name so that it would be something like server.database.contoso.com? This is primarily for "brand recognition" and not hard technical requirement. Would setting up a DNS CNAME work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

No currently you cannot change the DNS name. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939002/is-there-a-way-to-change-cloudapp-net-dns-name-in-windows-azure) thread on similar question.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely can - just create a CNAME on the domain you want and point it to your .database.windows.net domain.

The trick is that if you do this you then have to append the username with your slug.  So, if your original domain was this:

cooldata.database.windows.net

You might have setup an admin called cooldataadmin.  If you create an alias pointing from data.cooldomain.com to cooldata.database.windows.ent you would then access the data with the user cooldataadmin@cooldata.